# How do I get the contents of both pickle.dumps for my unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a function like this:

```
def save_data(self):
    nx.write_gpickle(self.graph, "popitgraph.pickle")
    f = open("node_color.pickle", "w")
    pickle.dump(self.colors, f)
    f.close()
    f = open("node_label.pickle", "w")
    pickle.dump(self.labels, f)
    f.close()
```

In my test I did this:

```
@patch("popit_to_networkx.nx.write_gpickle")
@patch("pickle.dump")
def test_networkx_save_data(self, mock_dump, mock_write_gpickle):
    # Just assign graph a value to make sure it's passed in
    from mock import mock_open
    m_file = mock_open()
    with patch("__builtin__.open", m_file):
        self.popit2networkx.graph = "hulahoop"
        self.popit2networkx.colors = {'color1', 'color2'}
        self.popit2networkx.labels = {'label1', 'label2'}
        self.popit2networkx.save_data()
        self.assertEqual(mock_write_gpickle.call_args,
                         call('hulahoop', 'popitgraph.pickle'))
        self.assertTrue(m_file.called)
        self.assertEqual(m_file.call_args,
                         call('node_label.pickle', 'w'))
```

When I try to look at `mock_dump.call_args` I always get the contents of the latest call, how do I get the contents of the previous call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the `mock_dump.call_args_list` [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list).